# passing javascript variable to php using object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, object, local-storage

Hello and thanks for the help in advance.  I'm new to JavaScript and ajax.  I'm trying to get a php code to display in the same page based on a variable that has been predefined elsewhere in the page.  I found the code below using an object to display the php in the same page.  my problem is when i try to add the variable it doesn't get passed with the php request. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

```
   <form id="locform" name="locform" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="box1" id="box1">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">    
   var y = localStorage.getItem("location");
   document.locform.box1.value = y;
   document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="loc.php?loc=" + y></object>';    
</script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: you haven't closed your string properly

Comment: Actually your script couldn't identify your div, move the script after div, or load script using window.onload. And you are passing `y` as string not as a variable!

Comment: Using an `<object />` to do an AJAX call is very creative but not your best bet. I would recommend you to look into AJAX calls. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) has a great tutorial.

Comment: You wrongly concatenation of 'y'. Please correct it with `data="loc.php?loc='+y+'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting y as a string not as variable, Try this:

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="loc.php?loc=' + y + '"></object>';
```